# How can I replace specific word in c# with parenthesis?

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

Consider the following string:

```
string s = "The man is (old).";
```

If I use:

```
Regex.Replace(s,@"\b\(old\)\b", @"<b>$&</b>");
```

The output is :
The man is (old).
But I would change the whole of the (old) word like this:
The man is **(old)**.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\b` won't match because `(` and `)` are not word characters. Is there a reason why you put them there, because you could just leave them out:

```
 string replaced = Regex.Replace(s,@"\(old\)", @"<b>$&</b>");
```

According to the [specs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx):

`\b` : The match must occur on a boundary between a \w (alphanumeric) and a \W (nonalphanumeric) character.

`-space-` and `)` are both nonalphanumeric. The same for `(` and `.`, so `\b` won't match in both cases.

Comment: I have a HTML Content and I have set the Multi line option in Regular Expression, but It doesn't work.

Comment: You're right. The reason is that `(` and `)` are not word characters, so `\b' won't match a word boundary. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might not even need a regex... try

```
string result = s.Replace("(old)", "<b>(old)</b>");
```

or

```
string result = s.Replace("(", "<b>(").Replace(")", ")</b>");
```

Comment: I have a HTML content and I would like use the Regular Expression,your solution works for me.but the others does not work.