# C# Multiple Word Replacement Issue

Tags: c#, string, replace

Consider the case where I want every occurrence of the phrase "hello world" in an article to be replaced with "I love apple". How should I write the code to do the replacement?

I am aware that I could simply use Replace function to do the replacement but it is not the most ideal way to do so (if I specify to replace the word "or" it will also do the replacement for the word "for" etc). Is there any other way I can do to achieve what I want?

Comment: "How should I write the code to do the replacement?". What have you tried? Is this an issue you are actually facing (note the FAQ says: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.").

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you read anything about string search and replace in C#? I mean, it's a fairly well covered topic. No doubt google returns no less than a hundred page that cover it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I replace a specific word in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884759/how-can-i-replace-a-specific-word-in-c)

Comment: @JonB: This question is slightly different. He wants to replace a word combination with another word combination without replacing parts of a word. So each string must be a whole word and the order matters (i assume).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using  [Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx) with lookbehind:

```
String urstring = Regex.Replace(urstring,"(?<=\W)or|^or","SS")
```

This will replace all "or" occurrences that are NOT preceded by a letter or digit.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can use regular expresion

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
public class Test
{
   public static void Main()
   {
       string input = "doin some replacement";
       string pattern = @"\bhello world'\b";
       string replace = "I love apple";
       string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replace);        
    }
}
```

following link might be helpful

[Way to have String.Replace only hit "whole words"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143642/way-to-have-string-replace-only-hit-whole-words)

Answer (score 0):

Use Regular Expressions. This has already been covered, please consult the following:

1. [How can I replace a specific word in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884759/how-can-i-replace-a-specific-word-in-c)
2. [replace text in a string with .net regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902706/replace-text-in-a-string-with-net-regexp)

Answer (score -1):

Try using regex like in here:

[How can I replace a specific word in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884759/how-can-i-replace-a-specific-word-in-c)

or here:

[How can I replace specific word in c# with parenthesis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439039/how-can-i-replace-specific-word-in-c-sharp-with-parenthesis)

Comment: That would fail if the word/phrase appears at the beginning or end of the string, or if it's followed by punctuation.